# Disconnect for WDS in production build version

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

[WDS error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUkac.png)

I have had a web application compiled with Webpack that has been running smoothly for several months then on a server reboot it no longer serves properly. I am receiving these errors in the console saying that it has disconnected from WDS, and the other errors that seem related to the issue.

All of the issues I have seen other post do not seem to solve my issue. I am serving up the built application with a static file server (NPM's serve package) so I am not sure why I am receiving WDS disconnect issues at all.

If anyone could shed some insight that would be deeply appreciated.

Here is my webpack config:

var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './src/index',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:5000'
  ],
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'map.js'
  },
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: 'style!css!autoprefixer!less'
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './src',
    port: 5000
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The

```
[WDS] Disconnected!
```

Error just happens when you reload the page so it's most likely unrelated. I would look deeper into the other errors you're getting.

It would be nice if you could be more specific about what you've tried. Also some information about your setup and what's hosting the static file server would be helpful. Have you tried the fix in this issue? It seems very similar. https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/416

first it suggests changing the entry line

```
'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.0:5000'
```

to

```
'webpack-dev-server/client?http://' + require("os").hostname() + ':5000/',
```

The secondary solution is to use the IP address of what's hosting the static file server directly. You will need to install the 'ip' package first then use this line.

```
'webpack-dev-server/client?http://' + require("ip").address() + ':5000/',
```

Again more information is needed about the host that's serving the files. It could have been a simple configuration change when you rebooted. Check that the port is correct/open. Check that the static file server is indeed still running. Try making the same calls to the server manually with requests.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I am just using this node static server to serve up the page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve

The link you provided is the first thread I follow to fix the issue to no avail. All other threads I looked at were very similar and I tried them as well. I dont have the links unfortunately. 

The issue doesnt just happen when I reload its all the time.

Also I am unsure why it has anything to do with the webpack-dev-server since I am serving up the production build and with a different server. Why would it still be logging stuff about WDS?

Comment: Could it be a script in your package.json causing NPM to launch the WDS

Comment: That wasnt it but that did give me some insight. I needed to remove the third element in the entry array.


    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:5000'

 That seemed to not make the production build reference WDS at all